# Can cached artifacts in a Artifactory remote repository be made immutable

Tags: artifactory

I have set up a remote docker repository that caches a docker registry.  I have pulled a docker image via a tag from the Artifactory remote, and the layers are now in the Artifactory cache.  If the tag is modified in the origin registry, will a subsequent pull from the remote get the new layers?  Is there any cache configuration to make the tags in the remote immutable?

Likewise, how can remote repositories for other package types be made immutable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the remote tag is modified then the updated image will be pulled into the local cache next time it’s requested from Artifactory. The only way I can think of to stop this is to set the remote repository offline in Artifactory.